# creating a dataframe using a dictionary with new columns in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, data-analysis

hi I have a dictionary,

```
 d={'Pricing': 1, 'Product': 1, 'Rates': 2, 'one': 1}
 columnsd=["one","two"]
```

I tried,

```
  df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=columnsd)
```

I am getting,

```
 ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

my desired df should be,

```
   one          two    
   Pricing       1
   Product       1
   Rates         2
   one           1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to tuples and use `pd.DataFrame`/`pd.DataFrame.from_records`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(d.items()), columns=columnsd)

       one  two
0  Product    1
1      one    1
2  Pricing    1
3    Rates    2
```

Comment: @Bharath I didn't realise you could call the constructor directly, lol

Comment: A tiny difference in speed of posting will take away the votes.

Comment: @Bharath I remember it happened to you once :p

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary keys will be treated as an index so use the .items() to create the dataframe i.e

```
d={'Pricing': 1, 'Product': 1, 'Rates': 2, 'one': 1}
columnsd=["one","two"]

df=pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()),columns=columnsd)
```

```
      one  two
0  Product    1
1      one    1
2  Pricing    1
3    Rates    2
```